# Hide and show div with links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this code that I will put in jsfiddle link bellow. Im making hide/show divs by clicking on links. Only problem is when I want to view a div  (second, third or fourth div), lets say the third one, it doesnt show up on top but benith the first and second invisible divs. Anybody got any idea how to make this right and put any selected div on the top of the page?

```
<body>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menu">
            <li><a href="javascript:show('link1')" id="link1">Felge</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:show('link2')" id="link2">Gume</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:show('link3')" id="link3">Branici</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:show('link4')" id="link4">Farovi</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="div" id="content1">
            <p>BBS</p>
            <p>ENKEI</p>
            <p>KONIG</p>
        </div>

        <div class="div" id="content2">
                <p>Michelin</p>
                <p>Hankook</p>
                <p>Sava</p>
        </div>

        <div class="div" id="content3">
            <p>AMG</p>
            <p>Brabus</p>
            <p>Original</p>
        </div>

        <div class="div" id="content4">
            <p>Angel Eyes</p>
            <p>Devil Eyes</p>
            <p>Original</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

```
function show(id) {

    if (id == 'link1') {
        document.getElementById("content1").style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("content2").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("content3").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("content4").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    else if (id == 'link2') {
        document.getElementById("content1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("content2").style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("content3").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("content4").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    else if (id == 'link3') {
        document.getElementById("content1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("content2").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("content3").style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("content4").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    else if (id == 'link4') {
        document.getElementById("content1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("content2").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("content3").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("content4").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}

function init() {

    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i].className == "div") {
            divs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    a.onclick = show;
}

window.onload = init;
```

`

https://jsfiddle.net/4qq6xnfr/

Comment: Change `style.visibility = 'hidden'` to `style.display = 'none'` to hide the div or `style.display = 'block'` to show the div. `display: none` will make it so that the div looks like it is removed from the page whereas `visibility: hidden` only makes it invisible (i.e. it still takes up space)

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? It looks like you included the file, but I can't see where you're actually using it.

Comment: Ahh, I was trying few diferent ways and codes so I forgot to delete the jQuery tag. Tnx for help guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`visibility: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) hides element but leaves the space occupied by it. You need to hide element with `display: none`:

```
document.getElementById("content1").style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("content2").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("content3").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("content4").style.display = 'none';
```

Also, you can optimize you code a little. Maybe like this:

```
function show(id) {
    var number = id.replace('link', '');
    var blocks = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=content");
    for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        blocks[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.querySelector('#content' + number).style.display = 'block';
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/4qq6xnfr/3/

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
element.style.display = 'none'; // Hide
element.style.display = 'block'; // Show
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to achieve this is as follows:

1. Change all the links from `javascript:show('link1')`, `javascript:show('link2')`, etc. to just `#content1`, `#content2`, etc.
2. You can now remove **all** of the javascript code.
3. Create a new CSS stylesheet (or use the `<style>` tags), and in the stylesheet, write the following -

   ```
   .div {
     display:none;
   }

   .div:target {
     display:block;
   }
   ```

That's it! I hope this helped you.